# Intel RealSense L515 not working on edge devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I went through and installed (cmake, make, make install) librealsense 2.3.6 from GitHub. I have done this countless times for previous cameras (D435, T235) successfully. But after installing it on the Raspberry Pi, or the Jetson Nano,  I am not seeing the L515 when I run realsense-viewer. The C and Python demos are also unable to see the device. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently there were some hidden flags that needed to be set:
cmake ../ -DFORCE_RSUSB_BACKEND=true -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=true -DBUILD_GRAPHICAL_EXAMPLES=true